# Problem with \usepackage{glossaries}

Tags: miktex, glossaries

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{First Section} 
Hello World
\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,
description={solution able to conduct electric current}}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

For the following example it will generate the following error

[image]

I suspect that the package didn't install properly, but I could not find anywhere in TexNicCenter to reinstall package. Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

I found where I could uninstall the package. The problem wasn't with the install of the package though. I still need help to fix this problem!

**UPDATE 2**

It compiles now, but the glossary page is not generated. Anyone that could help with it?

Comment: Texniccenter does not manage the package, it's the role of your Tex distribution (MikTex ou TexLive). Have you installed the package `datatool`? By googling datatool-base.sty, it seems to be related to this package...

Comment: Lionel is absolutely right: It is in no way related to TeXnicCenter (hence my edit). You must install `datatool`. If you‘d say, what TeX distribution you’ve installed, we could give more help.

Comment: I have installed the MiKTeX distribution. I added the `datatool` package now. And it compiles however I don't get any new page with the glossaries that I add. I updated my example with the changes to the document

Comment: @starcorn: The glossary is processed in a similar way to an index. That is, you compile with (pdf)latex, run `makeglossaries`, and then re-compile using (pdf)latex. From the [`glossaries` readme](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries): "The pack­age uses an in­dex­ing pro­gram to pro­vide the ac­tual glos­sary; ei­ther `makein­dex` or `xindy` may serve this pur­pose, and a Perl script is pro­vided to serve as in­ter­face." See section **1.3 Generating the Associated Glossary Files** of the [`glossaries` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Hello World \gls{electrolyte}`:

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{glossaries}    

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,
description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{First Section} 
Hello World \gls{electrolyte}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Now run

```
pdflatex yourfile.tex
makeindex.exe -s yourfile.ist -t yourfile.glg -o yourfile.gls yourfile.glo (from command prompt)
pdflatex yourfile.tex
```

Where `yourfile` is the name of your main tex file. Run `makeindex` through command prompt inside your folder where you have kept the tex file.

You will get:

[image]

Comment: The part when you run makeindex, I don't have some of the file. in the folder I miss `yourfile.glg`, `yourfile.gls`. Do I need to create them myself? And also is it possible to add the command prompt part in texniccenter, so I can have it automated instead?

Comment: @starcorn: They are created when you run that command. You need not create them. Or if texniccenter has an option to run makeglossaries, you better use it.

Comment: I had to run `latex myFileName` and then `makeglossaries myFileName` to generate the `glg` and `gls`.

Answer (score 0):

In build --> define output profiles, i have added **-l -s %tm.ist -o %tm.gls "%tm".glo** in the command line arguments to pass to MakeIndex :. It generate the glossary correctly

Comment: Can you please elaborate how exactly your solution solves the issue? (A little detail about unterstanding the misbehaviour&how exactly those arguments you pass to `makeindex` address the partial problems of the issue.)